# Cross-Site Request Forgery issue in fortify report

Tags: java

i am getting the CSRF in the following jsp.

```
<html:form action="CenterNotificationAction?method=acknowledgeNotification">
<logic:iterate id="user_Request_ID" name="addedSer" property="userRequestID">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="userRequestID" value="<bean:write name="user_Request_ID"/>">
</logic:iterate>
<logic:present name="addedSer" property="requestNotificationID">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="requestNotificationID" value="<bean:write name="addedSer" property="requestNotificationID"/>">
</logic:present>    

<tr>
<td><img src="/images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="" border="0"></td>
<td CLASS="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY"></td>
<td align="right"><html:submit property="Acknowledge" value="Acknowledge" styleClass="PSPUSHBUTTON" style="width:120px;"/></td>
</tr>
</html:form>
```

can any one suggest me how to resolve this??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to ensure that the http request cannot be forged by an attacker.  I don't have all the context so I'm not really sure what this request does, it seems like it captures an agreement from the user, which could be a critical thing to protect from forgery.

The typical way to fix this:
1.  Put a hidden field containing a cryptographiclly strong value used once and only once (a cryptographic nonce) in the form when you send it to the browser.  Keep a record of that nonce in the session on the server side.
2.  When the form is submitted compare the received nonce to the one that was sent to the browser.  If the two don't match then you reject the request.  If the two match you're ok.

OWASP has an antiCSRF JSP tag library that can be used for this purpose.  It's been a while since I've used but it worked well when I needed it.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFGuard_3_Token_Injection#JSP_Tag_Library

No, I'm not affiliated in any way with the OWASP project.  I also did this manually without the OWASP tag for a non-JSP project.  I can guide you thru how to do it without the OWASP tag if you want.

Good luck!